# Time-derivative of integral over sub-level set $s(t) := \int_{f^{-1}((-\infty,t])}p(x)dx$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, geometric-probability

Let $\mu$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb R^d$ with "sufficiently regular" density $p$. Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be a "sufficiently regular" function. Finally, for every $t \ge 0$, define
$$
s_f(t) := \mu(f^{-1}((-\infty,t])) = \int_{f^{-1}((-\infty,t])}p(x)dx
$$

> **Question.** *What is the derivative of $s_f$ w.r.t $t$ ?*

It seems I should be able to solve my problem in principle using Lemma 3.1 of [Malliavin Calculus for non Gaussian differentiable measures and surface measures in Hilbert spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05964). However, that paper is hard to parse for a non-expert like myself.

---

Now, suppose $f$ depends "smoothly" on a parameter $\theta$, i.e let $\Theta$ be a nonempty subset of some $\mathbb R^n$ and suppose $F:\mathbb R^d \times \Theta \to \mathbb R$ is "smooth", and for any $\theta \in \Theta$, define $s_\theta := s_{f_\theta}$, where $f_\theta(x):=F(x,\theta)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$.

> **Question.** *For every $t \ge 0$, what is the gradient of $\theta \mapsto s_\theta(t)$.*

### Examples

- *Linear:* $f(x) = w^\top x - c$, for some unit-vector $w \in \mathbb R^d$ and scalar $c \in \mathbb R$. Here $\theta = (w,c) \in \mathbb R^{d + 1}=:\Theta$.
- *Quadratic:* $f(x) = \pm (r^2-\|x\|^2)$, here $\theta = r^2 \in (0,\infty) =: \Theta$.

Comment: If $s_f$ is, e.g., continuously differentiable its derivative is a Lebesque density of the push forward measure $\mu\circ f^{-1}$. A trivial situation is a constant function $f$ for which $\mu\circ f^{-1}$ does not have a density.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thanks for the hint. Do you mean pushforward of $\mu$ under $f$, i.e $f_\# \mu$ as usually written in probability literature ? If so, then in the case of $f(x):=w^\top x-c$ and multi-variate Gaussian distribution $\mu = N(m,\sigma^2 I_d)$, your hint leads us to: $s_f'$ is the density of $N(w^\top m-c,\sigma^2\|w\|^2) = N(f(m),\sigma^2\|w\|^2)$, that is $s_f'(t) = \varphi((t-f(m))/(\sigma\|w\|))$, where $\varphi$ is standard Gaussian pdf. Does this computation look correct to you ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes,  $f_\sharp\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$. Your calculation seems correct.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thanks again. It seems a general way to compute the density of that push-forward is via "Mallavian calculus". In the case of **Example 1**, I can confirm (see below) that this kind of calculus gives the correct answer as computed via "brute-force" in my comment above. Any further insights are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment (but too long for that format) to suggest a simple and elementary approach:  we can write
$$s_f(t)=\int H(t-f(x))p(x)\,dx$$ and manipulate formally (but see below) to get
$$\frac{d}{dt}s_f(t)=\int \delta(t-f(x))p(x)\,,dx$$  where $H$ and $\delta$ are the Heaviside function and the Dirac distribution respectively. This suggests using the elementary theory of distributions for your computations, which can then be carried out in the concrete situations you describe using well-established formulae.

Similarly, if $$s_{\theta}(t)=\int H(t-f(x,\theta))p(x)\,dx,$$ we can compute its partial derivatives with respect to the parameters as
$$\int \delta(t-f(x,\theta))\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}f(x,\theta)\,p(x)\,dx.$$

Note that in order to make this rigorous, one requires, within the context of distribution theory, the notions of parametrised integrals, differentiation under the integral sign, composition of a distribution with a smooth function (and the chain rule) and the product of a smooth function and a distribution.  All of these are standard fare (they were developed by a cohort of prominent mathematicians in the 50´s and 60´s, together with methods for explicit computations for concrete functions--all this at the level of a first year analysis course).  The two   examples for $f$ that you mention are particularly simple.

In case of interest, I would be happy to include references.

Comment: Thanks for your input (upvoted). I'm accepted since it appears to be the best answer at the moment. I'd be grateful if you would include any specific references (and not maybe, say, some general monograph on the theory of distributions).

Comment: In the 60´s of the last century, a number of mathematicians addressed the task of providing an elementary approach to distributions (i.e., without using sophisticated duality theory for special classes of locally convex spaces).  Probably the most useful presentation of this theory, and the one most relevant for your question, was  given by J. Sebastiao e Silva.  This used to be rather inaccessible but is now easily available online.  Go to the site jss100.campus.ciencias.ulisboa.pt, then to publicacoes, Textos didaticos and you will find  III.1. Theory of distributions.

Answer (score 1):

---

### Update: Solution for Example 1

*It seems the right apparatus for studying such problems is *Malliavin calculus*, though I'm not at all yet familiar with the tool.*

---

So, let $G = (g_1,\ldots,g_d)$ be a standard Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb R^d$ and consider the Gaussian process defined by $Z(a) := \langle G,a\rangle = \sum_j a_j g_j$, for any $a \in \mathbb R^d$. The random variable "$f(x)$, $x \sim N(m,\Sigma)$" in the question can be written as

$$
X := Z(\widetilde w)-c+\sum_{j=1}^d w_j m_j,
$$
where $\widetilde w := \Sigma^{1/2}w \in \mathbb R^d$. Note that $\|\widetilde w\| = \|w\|_\Sigma := \sqrt{w^\top \Sigma w}$.

Let $S(X):=\delta(DX/\|DX\|^2)$, where $D$ (resp. $\delta$) is the *Malliavin derivative* (resp. *Skorohod integral*) operator. A simple computation gives $DX = \widetilde w$, and so
$$
S(X) = (1/\|\widetilde w\|^2)\sum_j \widetilde w_j G_j = (1/\|\widetilde w\|)Z(\widetilde w/\|\widetilde w\|)
$$

Therefore, thanks to **Proposition 2.1.1** of [Introduction to Malliavin Calculus](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/kunze/malliavin/Malliavin_skript.pdf), one obtains

$$
\begin{split}
s_f'(t) &= \mathbb E[1_{X \le t} S(X)] = \frac{1}{\|\widetilde w\|}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{(t-f(m))/\|\widetilde w\|}ze^{-z^2/2}dz = \varphi(\frac{t-f(m)}{\|\widetilde w\|})\\
&= \varphi(\frac{t-f(m)}{\|w\|_\Sigma})
\end{split}
$$
where $\varphi$ is the standard Gaussian pdf. This exactly matches the computation carried out in the comments section to the question above (where $\Sigma = \sigma^2 I_d$).